# starting Cassandra AssertionError

Tags: cassandra

When i try to start Cassandra, i received an AssertionError about "durable_wrıtes". I tried to install different Cassandra versions but nothing changed. OS is Ubuntu 16.04

```
Exception (java.lang.AssertionError) encountered during startup: Cannot find column durable_wrıtes
java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot find column durable_wrıtes
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowUpdateBuilder.add(RowUpdateBuilder.java:273)
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.makeCreateKeyspaceMutation(SchemaKeyspace.java:394)
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.makeCreateKeyspaceMutation(SchemaKeyspace.java:401)
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.saveSystemKeyspacesSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.finishStartup(SystemKeyspace.java:468)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:333)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:557)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:685)
ERROR 04:04:55 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot find column durable_wrıtes
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowUpdateBuilder.add(RowUpdateBuilder.java:273) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.makeCreateKeyspaceMutation(SchemaKeyspace.java:394) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.makeCreateKeyspaceMutation(SchemaKeyspace.java:401) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.schema.SchemaKeyspace.saveSystemKeyspacesSchema(SchemaKeyspace.java:267) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.finishStartup(SystemKeyspace.java:468) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:333) [apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:557) [apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:685) [apache-cassandra-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
```

Comment: Can you share more about your query? It sounds like a table issue, not a Cassandra version issue.

Comment: I just try to start cassandra with "bin/cassandra -f" command on command line. I never developed with Cassandra before. I dont know what i need to search.

Comment: I was using Ubuntu in my native language. I changed to English and now Cassandra is running without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the problem is the conversion from uppercase letter **I** to lowercase in Turkish

In Turkish local **I** is converted to **ı** so **DURABLE_WRITES** becomes **durable_wrıtes**. As Cassandra expects to find a column `durable_writes` it can't find so it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem on windows 10. My workaround was adding `user.language` and `user.country` JVM optiions to `cassandra.ps1` file. Which is executed by `cassandra.bat`

I added this line:

```
$env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS " + "-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US"
```

before:

```
    # Other command line params
    if ($H)
    {
        $env:JVM_OPTS = $env:JVM_OPTS + " -XX:HeapDumpPath=$H"
    }
```

in Main function of `cassandra.ps1`.

**A Note:**
If power shell script is not being executed for some reason (on windows 7 it didn't) add these JVM options to legacy start up options in `cassandra.bat`.

```
REM JVM Opts we'll use in legacy run or installation
set JAVA_OPTS=-ea^
 -Duser.language=en^
 -Duser.country=US^
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: i added below line at the end of cassandra-env.sh

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Duser.language=en"

JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Duser.country=US"`
and it s working.

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, I added

```
JVM_OPTS = "$JVM_OPTS -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US"
```

on 217. line of /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh

Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I also tried and it worked that the below line at the end of cassandra-env.sh

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Duser.language=en" 
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Duser.country=US"
```